# Sum different levels of a vector together within id

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, aggregate, summarize

'My data could look like this

```
id <- c('A1','A1','A1','A1','B2','B2','B2','B2','C3','C3','C3','C3')
event <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','a', 'b', 'c', 'd','a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
value <- c(3,2,5,3,6,5,7,6,4,5,6,7)
Dat <- data.frame(id, event, value)
```

Now what i would like to do is sum certain values together based on a different levels of an event within id. For example, within each id combining a, b and c that would result a new level, lets say comb_abc (for id A1 that would be 10). Then, ID A1 would have only two levels on an event vector "comb_abc" = 10 and "some_name" (d) = 3. Here i am changing the levels a, b and c to comb_abc and d to some_name. And the same would happen for each id.
How can i do that?

THNAK YOU!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the values of `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` into `'comb_abc'` and change rest of them (`'d'`) to `'some_name'` and take `sum` of `value` for each `id` and `event`.

```
aggregate(value~id+event, transform(Dat, 
         event = ifelse(event %in% c('a','b','c'), 'comb_abc', 'some_name)), sum)
```

In `dplyr` this can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)

Dat %>%
  mutate(event = if_else(event %in% c('a','b','c'), 'comb_abc', 'some_name')) %>%
  group_by(id, event) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))

#  id    event     value
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 A1    comb_abc     10
#2 A1    some_name     3
#3 B2    comb_abc     18
#4 B2    some_name     6
#5 C3    comb_abc     15
#6 C3    some_name     7
```

Comment: Oh and one more question: If i have more than one level of event to sum. Lets say i combine a, b, c to comb_abc, and then i combine also d, e, f to comb_def. Is there hint how to proceed? I was trying to extend aggregate code, but i got wrong results.

Comment: @timothy You can extend the `ifelse` as well but if you have such multiple conditions to check you can use `case_when` like this : `Dat %>% mutate(event = case_when(event %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')~ 'comb_abc', event %in% c('d','e','f')~ 'comb_def', TRUE ~'some_name')) %>%  group_by(id, event) %>% summarise(value = sum(value))`. You could extend this to any number of levels.

Comment: I like this case_when, it is clear and easy to understand, but unfortunately with this code I only get the overall sum ie. 
           value     59

Comment: Somehow it feels like it does not take group_by into account

Comment: Do you have `plyr` loaded? Restart R and load only `dplyr` and try or use `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: Ah there is always some little trick hiding from me:) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
  value ~ id + cbind(event = c("some_name", "comb_abc")[1 + event %in% c("a", "b", "c")]),
  Dat,
  sum
)
```

which gives

```
  id     event value
1 A1  comb_abc    10
2 B2  comb_abc    18
3 C3  comb_abc    15
4 A1 some_name     3
5 B2 some_name     6
6 C3 some_name     7
```

---

If you have more than one level to combine, here is a small example showing you a possible option

```
set.seed(1)
v <- sample(letters[1:8],20,replace = TRUE)
comb <- list(c("a","b","c"),c("d","e","f"),c("g","h"))
res <- sapply(comb, paste0,collapse = "")[Reduce(`+`,lapply(seq_along(comb), function(k) k*(v %in% comb[[k]])))]
```

which gives

```
> res
 [1] "abc" "def" "gh"  "abc" "abc" "def" "gh"  "abc" "def" "abc" "abc" "abc"
[13] "abc" "def" "def" "abc" "def" "def" "abc" "gh"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with two combinations, but I don't know how to sum more levels.

Comment: @timothy I updated my answer with a small example. Please check it out